# i have a csv file that contains time series data from one single subject. i want to perform windowing on that taking one row as a single element

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

My csv:

```
 X    Y      Timestamp      Test ID
 213  205    1351716        0
```

with several such rows (2500 of them)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use `df = pandas.read_csv(fileName)`, then iterate through the rows with `df.iterrows()` or get all values in a single column with `df['columnName']`

Pandas also has built in windowing operations:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/window.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/window.html